# Splitting HTML code into multiple files using webpack

Tags: html, webpack

I'm trying desperately to split my HTML into multiple files using Webpack. I've tried the "<%= require() %>" method but doesn't work. Only work with my images. See my webpack config below. Basically what I wanna do is this:

file1.html

```
<h1>This is my file number 1</h1>
```

file 2.html

```
<h1>This is my file number 2</h1>
<%= require("file1.html") %>
```

And then webpack when rendering the index.html file, will bundle those two files together.
This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");



module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/assets/js/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        clean: {
            keep: /images\//, // Keep these assets under 'ignored/dir'.
        },
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                          publicPath: "./"
                        }
                    },
                      {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {importLoaders: 2, url: false},
                    },
                      {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                          postcssOptions: {
                            config: path.resolve(__dirname, 'postcss.config.js'),
                          },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }, 

            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            filename: "[name].[hash:6].[ext]",
                            outputPath: 'images/',
                            emitFile: true,
                            esModule: false
                        },
                    },
                ], 
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          title: 'Caching',
          template: "./src/template.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
              vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Any help is more than welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It is not really possible out-of-box with either `Webpack` or `html-webpack-plugin`. However, you have multiple possible options to achieve this.

### Option 1

Read the HTML files that you intend to inject into your main HTML and then use template context using `templateParameters` to pass your HTML content. For example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const files = {
  file1: fs.readFileSync('file1.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' }),
  file2: fs.readFileSync('file1.html', { encoding: 'utf-8' })
};


module.exports = {
  // ...other configuration
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Caching',
      template: './src/template.html',
      templateParameters: {
        files
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Your `template.html` file would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><%= files.file1 %></div>
    <div><%= files.file2 %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The limitation here is that you can have includes only inside the `template.html` file. You cannot have recursive include like `file2.html` from `file1.html`. But this will work only if you intend to generate single HTML file.

### Option 2

You can use the plugins for `html-webpack-plugin`. [This plugin](https://github.com/colbyfayock/html-webpack-partials-plugin) provides a nice support for partials. And, then there are few more plugins like [this](https://github.com/mfoitzik/html-webpack-simple-include-plugin) and [this](https://github.com/Jaid/inject-body-webpack-plugin) that can be used. Again these plugins will help you augment your generated html template and not support recursive include inside the html files.

### Option 3

Using `html-loader` in combination `extract-loader`. This approach is flexible and can be used in multiple ways including using `posthtml` but it involves lots of configuration. You will have to write your own plugin in combination with other template loader that supports partials like [handlebar-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-loader) and then emit the HTML file.

### Updates on comments

There are the two options you can try. First do not try to require the images inside the html partial. Instead add image using root relative paths like:

```
<-- partial.html --!>
<img src="/my/root/relative/image.png" />
```

The use Webpack **copy plugin** to copy the images into your `dist` folder.

I have not fully tried it but the second option is to disable the loader of `html-webpack-plugin`. Instead use `html-loader` with the plugin like below. By introducing the `html-loader`, the HTML file will be processed, the images would be picked up by the `file-loader` before the final HTML is seen by the html plugin.

```
const config = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      }],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hi Harshal,

Thank you for your answer. The first option works really well to split my HTML code, however, I'm facing now another issue. Indeed my images are not loaded anymore into the final HTML file. In file1, I'm using <%= require() %> which work fine on the main template but doesn't work on the partials. Any suggestions?